# Repeating the same Random Forests through gbm is inconsistent?

Tags: r, boosting

I've noticed that when running a piece multiple times, the gbm produced (see below) produces slightly different results when viewing the summary.

Should that be expected? I.e. running gbm regression is not consistent?

```
file.gbm <- gbm(formula, data = my_data
            , distribution = 'bernoulli'
            , shrinkage = 0.01
            , n.minobsinnode = 30
            , interaction.depth = 3
            , n.trees = 500)
summary(file.gbm)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In GBM you have an option called bag.fraction. The help file specifies this as following:

> the fraction of the training set observations randomly selected to
>   propose the next tree in the expansion. This introduces randomnesses
>   into the model fit. If bag.fraction<1 then running the same model
>   twice will result in similar but different fits. gbm uses the R random
>   number generator so set.seed can ensure that the model can be
>   reconstructed.

The default setting in GBM is bag.fraction = 0.5. If you want your gbm call to return the same result, use set.seed before calling gbm.

Comment: In other words, this is stochastic gradient boosting if bag.fraction < 1?